# How to find angle of triangle inside circle?

Tags: triangles

[image: Angle of triangle inside circle]

Hi there,

In the above diagram:

Q is the center of the circle,
PAT is a tangent to the circle, PR is parallel to AC, angle CAT = x. Prove that angle ABC = x.

I started off by going 90 - x to find CAB. Then used co-interior angles to find AQR, and then found out BQR.

I'm just curious, in this question, can I assume that QRB and ACB are right angled triangles? Becuase if they were, I would think the question would state that. How would I solve this?

Comment: Triangle $QRB$ is not a right triangle. But the line $PR$ seems to be irrelevant to what you have to prove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Thale's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27s_theorem) states $\angle ACB$ is a right angle since $AB$ is a diameter. As $\angle BAT$ is also a right angle due to $PAT$ being tangent to the circle at $A$ (as stated in [Tangent lines to circles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_lines_to_circles), "The radius of a circle is perpendicular to the tangent line through its endpoint on the circle's circumference."), you have $\angle CAB = 90^{\circ} - x$ (as you already stated in your question) and, thus, $\angle ABC = x$ due to the sum of the angles in a triangle being $180^{\circ}$.

Comment: So the angle BRQ is also right angled, right?

Comment: Sorry, I meant angle B, the intersection point close to R, and Q?

Comment: And how does PAT being a tangent make BAT right angled?

Comment: @chris If by "the intersection point close to R, and Q" you mean the point where $BC$ and $QR$ intersect (let's call it point $S$), then it is right angled also because since $PR$ is parallel to $AC$ means that $\angle BSQ = \angle BCA = 90^{\circ}$.

Comment: @chris I didn't realize you didn't know about the radius of a circle to the point where a tangent line touches the circle is perpendicular to the tangent line. I've added a link to Wikipedia's article about this and their statement of it. I hope this explains it to you.